# How to run C program in Netbeans

Tags: c, netbeans

I am trying to run the dmtx project from Git (link: https://github.com/dmtx/dmtx-utils) in Netbeans. I have configured the `Project Properties` in NetBeans and the project is building correctly.

When I run a particular C file (dmtxwrite.c) through bash it gives the correct output. As mentioned in the README, the correct way to run it in Bash  is:

`$ echo -n 123456 | dmtxwrite > image.png`.

Now my question is how can I do the same using NetBeans?

Till now I only found answers related to passing command line arguments. However, that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I do the same using NetBeans?

- Select your C project in the **Projects** panel.
- Right-click it to open the context menu, then select **Properties > Run > Run Command**.
- Enter your command to be run in the **Run Command** field.

  [image]
- This is the **Help** for **Run Command** in NetBeans 8.2:

  *Enter a command to be executed when you run the project. The IDE runs the command as /bin/sh -c "run-command" which enables you to use any shell syntax including redirection and pipes. **Type the command in the Run Command field the same way you would run it from the command line.** For example, you could type my-script -opt1 -opt2 to run a script and specify two options, or mycommand > output.log to run your command and send the output to a logfile. The Run Command list maintains history of previous entries so you can go back to the default value or select among several different commands you have entered.*